# How to save a section of a pdf

Tags: pdf

I have been sent a massive pdf with over 500 pages, of which I only need the final 30 or so. Is there a way I can save just the last pages as a seperate pdf document?

Comment: Check my out the answers over at [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf/282453). The Q&A orimarily concerns Linux and Ubuntu but some of the tools shown there are cross-platform and should work on Windows as well (e.g. `pdfsam`).

Comment: @Glutanimate My god that looks tough. I thought there would be a feature similar to printing, where you can just select a range of pages

Comment: Well, it's Linux, so some things are admittedly tougher than on other platforms. Another method that just came to my mind is using a [PDF printer](http://superuser.com/questions/102302/need-a-fast-reliable-pdf-printer) to output a PDF file. With this I suppose you would be able to set the page range in the same manner as you would when printing a file. But I fear I can't help you with setting it up since I've never used one before. Other users might be able to do so, though. To anyone reading this: Feel free to compile an answer based on my suggestions (or other ideas for that matter).

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it possible to delete some pages of a pdf document?](http://superuser.com/questions/517986/is-it-possible-to-delete-some-pages-of-a-pdf-document), http://superuser.com/questions/446674 and many more.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install a PDF printer like [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) (As Glutanimate already mentioned)

[image]
<sup>Example with PDF-X Change Viewer and PDFCreator</sup>

- Download & install a PDF printer (there are many [alternatives which work similar](http://alternativeto.net/software/pdfcreator/))
- Open your PDF with your favority software like Adobe Reader or PDF-XChange Viewer
- Open the print dialog
- Choose your newly installed Printer
- Head down to the section where you choose the pages you want
- Click print and you will be asked for a destination and file name

Comment: I just tried doing the same in Foxit Reader and it works in the same way using its inbuilt PDF printer. You could try looking in your reader print menu for a similar option.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the commandline tool [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) (= the [PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)).

**Example:**

```
pdftk A=in1.pdf cat A130-160 output out1.pdf
```

As suggested in other answers, "printing" the required pages to a PDF printer is a good option. My favorite for this is [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/).

**Edited:**

In case you don't like commandline tools, you can control [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) using [Dirk Paehl's GUIPDFTK](http://www.paehl.de/pdf/):

[image]

Just enter the page number range as "CAT from:" and "CAT to:".